# Как в текстовом редакторе (блокнот, Sublime Text) дополнить каждую из строк?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text

Есть файл на большое количество строк. Нужно в начале каждой строки дописать набор символов, например, `123`. Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: под блокнотом тут какой блокнот имеется ввиду?

Answer (score 5):

В Sublime Text можно выбрать пункт меню **Find** | **Replace...**, включить режим регулярных выражений, иконка **.***, ввести в первое текстовое поле регулярное выражение начала строки

```
^
```

А во второе поле для замены

```
123
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать то же самое с концом строки?

Comment: Для обозначения конца строки в регулярных выражениях используется символ $

Answer (score 3):

1. Выделяете нужные строки
2. Ctrl+Shift+L
3. Home/End
4. 123